# azure u-sql table - how to read from python

Tags: python, azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I have created U-SQL Table in Azure Data Lake Analytics, I need to extract specific rows from that table using Python, any help please?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. We do require you to show that you did put in some effort before asking a question. This question is therefore off-topic. Have you tried google yet, there are python example available, see https://github.com/Azure/usql/blob/master/Examples/PythonExamples/PythonExamples/TweetExtract.usql for example

Comment: Thanks, yes this code I got multiple times in my search, BUT I want data in Python directly, not as output in DataLake, trying avoid that step of reading the output again. Any help.

Comment: At the moment that is not possible, there is a request for it though: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/327234-data-lake/suggestions/11266677-support-interactive-workloads-within-adl-analytics

Answer (score 0):

To lift Peter Bons' reply into an answer:

You currently do not have an interactive, direct to client, mode for U-SQL in Azure DataLake Analytics.

As a work-around, you could write a shim that does model it by writing the resulting file behind the scenes and downloading it.

Please make sure to register your request (and indicate that you want it for U-SQL specifically :)) at http://aka.ms/adlfeedback.